# unable to compile jsp class

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

```
**HTTP Status 500 - Unable to compile class for JSP: **

type Exception report

message Unable to compile class for JSP:

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: [/usr/local/easy/share/easy-tomcat7/work/Catalina/paykar.co.in/jsp/org/apache/jsp/rechargeMobile_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. com.RechargeMobile resolves to a package

An error occurred at line: [15] in the generated java file: [/usr/local/easy/share/easy-tomcat7/work/Catalina/paykar.co.in/jsp/org/apache/jsp/rechargeMobile_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. com.MobileInfo resolves to a package

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:463)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:378)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:353)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:340)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:646)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.42 logs.
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a wrong import in your JSP file.

There is a clear message in your logs:

> An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file:
>   [/usr/local/easy/share/easy-tomcat7/work/Catalina/paykar.co.in/jsp/org/apache/jsp/rechargeMobile_jsp.java]
>   Only a type can be imported. com.RechargeMobile resolves to a package

This means that you should have a line like following:

```
<%@ page import="com.MobileInfo" %>
```

But this is a package and not a class.
Try to change it as follow for importing a package:

```
<%@ page import="com.MobileInfo.*" %>
```

Otherwhise change ir as follow for importing spacific class you need:

```
<%@ page import="com.MobileInfo.YourClassName" %>
```